# Declarar una variable global en Jquery

Tags: jquery

### ¿Cómo puedo declarar una variable Jquery de manera global?

He buscado la manera de declarar una variable de manera global, en el que pueda acceder al valor de un `<input>` ya que el problema está, en que la variable es utilizada en por lo menos en otras 20 funciones diferentes. Usualmente declaro las funciones de la siguiente forma:

```
function Funcion1(){
    var valor1 = $('#objeto1').val();
    var valor2 = $('#objeto2').val();
    var valor3 = $('#objeto3').val();
    
    Generar(valor1,valor2,valor3);
}

/*
* mismos objetos utilizados que en Funcion1
*/
function Funcion2(){
    var valor0 = "objeto";
    var valor1 = $('#objeto1').val();
    var valor2 = $('#objeto2').val();
    var valor3 = $('#objeto3').val();
    
    Otro(valor0,valor1,valor2,valor3);
}

... (n funciones)
```

**¿Cuál es la forma correcta de declarar de manera global un** `var dato = $('#dato').val();` **?**

Aquí muestro un ejemplo de cómo es mi idea:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  Tu nombre:<br>
  <input id="dato" type="text">
  <button id="boton">ok</button>
<script>
    var saludo = 'Hola ';
    var dato = $('#dato').val();  //¿Cuál es la mejor manera?
    
    $('#boton').click(function(){
      alert(saludo + '\r\n' + dato); //no obtiene el dato de manera global
    });
</script>
```

Comment: La variable "dato" obtiene el valor al inicio de la carga de la página, no tienes nada que indique que cada vez que ingreses algo en el campo "dato" la variable "dato" obtenga ese nuevo valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código que tienes de prueba está bien, pero en ningún momento le dices a la variable que debe tomar el valor que introduces en el input cada vez que lo cambies. Así que te dejo este ejemplo y espero te sirva:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var saludo = 'Hola ';
    var dato;
    $("#dato").on("blur", function(){
    dato = $(this).val();
    });
    $('#boton').click(function(){
      alert(saludo + ' ' + dato);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  Tu nombre:<br>
  <input id="dato" type="text">
  <button id="boton">ok</button>
```

---

Lo que hace la función `.blur()` es detectar el momento en que se desenfoca un elemento, en este caso cuando se escribe en el input y luego se aprieta el botón, al apretar el botón se pierde el foco del input y se activa la función.